# Getting input text values on Rect using onChange misses first letter when typing and when deleting it misses too

Tags: reactjs, components, onchange

I have a small text field to filter a object array on my React app but when I type the onChange event skips the first character so it's not filtering the array correctly then when I delete the text it does not delete the first letter I wrote so to remove the filter you must reload the page.

This is my app:

```
    function App() {

  const [memes, setMemes] = useState([]);
  const [filteredMemes, setFilteredMemes] = useState([]);
  // const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function getData() {
      await getMemes();
    })();
  }, []);

  const getMemes = async () => {
    const results = await memeService.getMemes();
    setMemes(results.data.data.memes);
    setFilteredMemes(memes);
  }

  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    
    const filter = event.target.value;

    setFilteredMemes(memes);

    filteredMemes.filter((meme) => meme.name.toUpperCase().search(filter.toUpperCase()) >= 0);

  }

  return (
    <>
      <Nav handleSearch={handleSearch} />
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/:id/edit" children={<Editor />} />
          <Route path="/:id/new" children={<New />} />
          <Route path="/">
            <div className='container'>
              {filteredMemes.map(meme => <Meme key={meme.id} meme={meme} />)}
            </div>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
        
      </Router>
      
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

This is the Nav component that contains the input:

```
import './Nav.css';

const Nav = ({handleSearch}) => {

    return (
        <div className='nav'>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Search' onChange={handleSearch} />
            <a href='/'>Home</a>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Nav;
```

When I check on console the values that I'm gettin on the `handleSearch` function always gets the first letter as white space therefore when you erase the filter the results are no set to the full array.

Comment: You don't need to keep `filter` in the state, remove that and use `const filter=event.target.value` in the handler instead

Comment: Yes it works without using the Sate but now when I delete the search the results dont update :(

Comment: Yes the filtre variable changes it’s values but the results array doesn’t

Comment: Wait, you replace the original `memes` with filtered , so you can never get the filtered out ones back. You need to keep an unfiltered list for the reference

Comment: Still don't work :(

Comment: Can you update your post with what you have now?

Comment: I just post my code

Comment: Try reading this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately if it is too confusing, I can explain it simpler. But the way you're using state cannot work

Comment: I think I get it, but the useState can be called when changing a variable not state?

Comment: the filtered state I know it can work but tryed almost everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

```
setMemes(results.data.data.memes); //you request React to update memes at some point in the future 
  setFilteredMemes(memes); // you set filteredMemes to memes, which is still [] at this point

 setFilteredMemes(memes); // you request to change filteredMemes to the unfiltered version (again at some later point)

 filteredMemes.filter((meme) => meme.name.toUpperCase().search(filter.toUpperCase()) >= 0); //filter creates a new array, not assigned to anything
```

Should be

```
  setMemes(results.data.data.memes); 
  setFilteredMemes(results.data.data.memes); 

  setFilteredMemes(memes.filter((meme) => meme.name.toUpperCase().search(filter.toUpperCase()) >= 0));
```

Comment: ok I see it now why it wasnt working so frustating by the way is there any course that could help me to get a better understanding of React. Yesterday you had to cover me too. Thanks Nadia

Comment: I almost feel responsible for your memes now! The official React tutorial is reasonably good https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: I will give you 60% of the credit! It's a side project I started to learn React I usually use Angular with no problem but don't know why I get constantly stuck with React but will take a look to the link you shared me